# Put Html structure in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Hi I have created a custom drupal module and in my module I have to fetch data from database using while loop and print the data within this ul,li structure.Please let me know how could I do so

```
<ul class="catCol"><li><div class="itemLine"><div class="itemTitle"><a href="test_film.html"><font><font>test film</font></font></a></div><div class="itemCategory"><font><font>Pharmacy and Wholesale</font></font></div>
                                                                                                       <div class="itemDate"><span class="date"><font><font>11 Feb 2013</font></font></span></div>
                                                                                               </div>
                                                                                               <div style="clear:both;"></div>                        
                                                                                       </li>
```

I am new in drupal so if anyone could help me with this issue it would be appreciable.

Comment: You can do this in a cleaner way as creating a template file. See hook_theme for further information.

Answer (score 2):

```
function your_callback(){
  return theme('custom_output', array('results' => $results)); // $results an array with results from database
}

function your_module_name_theme() {
 return array(
  'custom_output' => array(
   'file' => 'your_template.tpl.php', // place your file in 'templates' folder of your module folder
   'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'your_module_name') .'/templates'
  )
 );
}
```

In your 'your_template.tpl.php' you will be able to put php and html as well. Results selected from database are reachable from your template file in $variables['results'] variable.

Comment: I wish I had seen this advice a couple of years ago! This is easily the most elegant and maintainable solution.